# Restrict specific file types for Woocommerce uploads only (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, upload, file-type, restrict

I am using Wordpress with the [Woocommerce plugin](https://woocommerce.com). In Woocommerce it is possible to create virtual/digital downloadable products. I want to restrict specific file types for the **Woocommerce uploads** only.

[woocommerce file upload field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkd4j.jpg)

I already found solutions to restrict file types for the standard Wordpress uploads, but not for the Woocommerce uploads.

I want to allow people to upload any file type in the standard Wordpress upload --- but only want to allow them to upload archive types (.zip, .rar, .7z ...) in the Woocommerce upload field.

Woocommerce uploads are located in wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2018/01/...

Maybe it is important in finding a solution for my problem.

Edit 1//

Standard Wordpress upload restriction looks like this (PHP):

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','restrict_mimes_for_author');
function restrict_mimes_for_author($mimes) {
  if (!current_user_can('author')) {
    return;
  }

  $mimes = array('pdf' => 'application/pdf');

  return $mimes;
}
```

or

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','restrict_mime');
function restrict_mime($mimes) {
$mimes = array(
                'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
                'gif' => 'image/gif',
);
return $mimes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce by default keep the files related to it inside woo-commerce upload folder, so if you can filter out the file type at the point of coming on this folder then you can differentiate between normal and woo-commerce upload.

Hope it gives some clue out of this.

Thanks